# Profiling of popup. Is it possible?

Tags: debug, popup, profiler

I'm going to run **profiler** for one page in admin area. It opened in popup.
I enabled profiler in **system / configuration**, uncommented `Varien_Profiler::enable();` in index.php

**Profiler** started working, but it doesn't work for my popup. 
Is there any way how to profile in that case? Maybe put info in some log file.

Comment: Found one perfect free extension which helped me to solve it. If I post it here - it will look like an advertising. If it's ok - I can share it with you, moreover it appeared in this community many times. If no - simply vote for deletion.

Comment: I believe you can share it here and mark it as answer as well. Don't forget to add the "disclaimer" though.